# Jquery .submit with function() will not fire, without function() it will

Tags: jquery, html

When a user selects a file(image, video, etc..) from open dialog I would the form to auto submit and I'm looking to get a response back from my controller method telling success or error.

If I call the jquery submit like so it will work fine:

```
 $("#fileupload2").submit(); //fileupload2 is a form tag
```

As soon as I add something like this it won't:

```
 $("#fileupload2").submit(function () { alert('hello'); });
```

I have no idea why as soon as I add the function inside it won't get called. There are no errors that I see in the browser development tools. My HTML looks like this:

```
<form id="fileupload2" action="/Home/UploadFiles" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
    <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
    <span>Add files...</span>
    <input id="fileupload" type="file" onchange="uploadSelectedFile(this);" name="file">
</div>
@*<input type="submit" />*@
</form>

 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#fileupload2").submit(function (e) {
        alert('hello'); $.post('/Home/UploadFiles', $('#fileupload2').serialize(), function (data) {
            alert(data);
        });
        return false;
    });
});

   function uploadSelectedFile() {
       $("#fileupload2").submit();
   }

  </script>
```

I am calling the jquery submit in uploadSelectedFile method onchange. Any advice or ideas on why this is happening I'd appreciate it. To me this seems right.

Controller Method:

```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult UploadFile() {
        //Some code
        return Json("success"); //or error
    }
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? putting a function into it means you are creating a callback function when the form is submit

Comment: I'm trying to get a response back from my controller method where the form is being posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#fileupload2").submit();
```

The above will submit the form

The below will **NOT** submit the form at all, but just do something when the form is submitted, it's an event handler bound to the submit event, so whenever the form is submitted, programatically or with the default button, the below will alert.

```
$("#fileupload2").submit(function () { alert('hello'); });
```

Comment: Basically I want to bind a function that gets the result of my executed code from my controller when the form is submitted

Comment: The bottom one binds a function to whenever the form is submitted, and a form can be submitted with the top one or by someone clicking the submit button (no JS). How you get the code from the controller is up to you, as I have no idea how you've set that up, but most of the time submitting a form will reload the page, making any javascript pretty much null and void, and start over etc, and if that is what you're trying to avoid, you'll need to use ajax.

Comment: right, returning false would stop the reload. So really I need both submits, with and without the callback function. I did that it works but now nothing is being passed in the parameter in my method. I revised my code above to show you.

Answer (score 2):

Without a callback, you are triggering the `submit` event, which submits the form.

With a callback, you are binding that function to the `submit` event, which means that when the form is submitted, that function will be executed.

What are you trying to do?

Comment: submit the form to the post method in my controller and get a result to be sent back

Comment: I revised my question above.

Comment: Basically I want to bind a function that gets the result of my executed code from my controller when the form is submitted

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#fileupload2").submit(function() {
 alert("Your Form is submited");
});
```

Comment: Yea this doesn't tell me much. I understand the syntax.